# Order of Odd Elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

I'm wondering if there is a way to calculate the order of odd numbers in the cyclic ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$. I found a [paper](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s18/m3341/ZnZ.pdf) that shows that for any odd $x$, $x^{2^{n-2}} \equiv 1 \mod{2^n}$, and that the order of 5 is exactly that (section 6). But is there a way to figure out the order of other elements, without just computing powers until you hit 1? I'm particularly interested in the case where $n = 8$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very easy method for each $a$ where $a \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $a \not\equiv 1 \bmod 2^n$. Find the highest power of $2$ dividing $a - 1$, say $a - 1 = 2^kb$ where $2 \leq k \leq n-1$ and $b$ is odd. Another way of describing $k$ is that $a \equiv 1 \bmod 2^k$ and $a \not\equiv 1 \bmod 2^{k+1}$. Then $a \bmod 2^n$ has order $2^{n-k}$, where $k$ is the number of $2$'s dividing $a-1$.

**Example**.  Consider $a = 97$. What's the order of $a \bmod 2^8$? We have $a-1 = 96 = 2^5 \cdot 3$, so $a \equiv 1 \bmod 2^5$ but $a \not\equiv 1 \bmod 2^6$. The order of $97 \bmod 2^8$ is $2^{8-5} = 2^3$. Indeed, $97^8 \equiv 1 \bmod 2^8$ and $97^4 \equiv 129 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 2^8$.

What about the order of $a \bmod 2^n$ if $a \equiv 1 \bmod 2$ but $a \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$?  For $n \geq 3$, $a$ and $-a$ have the same order mod $2^n$, and $-a \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, so just use the previous method on $-a$.

**Example**.  Consider $a = 159$. What's the order of $a \bmod 2^8$? We have $a-1 = 158 = 2 \cdot 79$, so $a \equiv 1 \bmod 2$ but $a \not\equiv 1 \bmod 4$. Let's look instead at $-a = -159 \equiv 97 \bmod 2^8$, for which we already determined the order is $8$, and $159 \bmod 2^8$ also has order $8$: $159^8 \equiv 1 \bmod 2^8$ and $159^4 \equiv 129 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 2^8$.

The same idea works for a modulus that is an odd prime power when $a \equiv 1 \bmod p$ (it's not necessary to focus first on $a \equiv 1 \bmod p^2$ like when $p=2$). If $a \not\equiv 1 \bmod p^n$ where $n \geq 2$, then $a-1 = p^kb$ where $p \nmid b$ and $1 \leq k \leq n-1$. Then $a \bmod p^n$ has order $p^{n-k}$, where $k$ is the number of $p$'s dividing $a-1$.

**Example**. Consider $a = 106$. What's the order of $a \bmod 3^8$? We have $a-1 = 3 \cdot 35$, so $a \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ but $a \not\equiv 1 \bmod 3^2$. The order of $106 \bmod 3^8$ is $3^{8-1} = 3^7 = 2187$. Indeed, $106^{3^7} \equiv 1 \bmod 3^8$ and $106^{3^6} \equiv 4375 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 3^8$.

Comment: I was just writing an answer to this effect myself.  For others:  the proof of this relies on the key calculation in the usual proof of the cyclicity of $(\mathbb Z/p^n \mathbb Z)^{\times}$ for $p$ odd (or the group of elements congruent to $1 \pmod 4$ when $p = 2$):  if $a-1$ is divisible by $p$ with multiplicity exactly $k$, then $a^p-1$ is divisible by $p$ with multiplicity exactly $k+1$, except in the case $p=2$, $k=1$.

Comment: Also, a trivial correction:  $a$ and $-a$ have the same order mod $2^n$ except in the silly case where one of them is $1$ and the other is $-1$.

Comment: In terms of the $p$-adic valuation, if $a \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for *odd* $p$, so ${\rm ord}_p(a-1) \geq 1$, then ${\rm ord}_p(a^j-1) = {\rm ord}_p(j) + {\rm ord}_p(a-1)$ for all $j \geq 1$. Thus ${\rm ord}_p(a^{p^r}-1) = r + {\rm ord}_p(a-1)$ for all $r \geq 0$.  So if $p^k$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $a-1$ and $n > k$, then the least $r$ making ${\rm ord}_p(a^{p^r} - 1) \geq n$ is $r = n-k$. The analogous starting formula when $p = 2$, ${\rm ord}_2(a^j-1) = {\rm ord}_2(j) + {\rm ord}_2(a-1)$ for all $j \geq 1$, is true provided ${\rm ord}_2(a-1) \geq 2$, meaning $a \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, and that's not a phenomenon that's restricted to $\Bbb Z_{2^n}$—calculating orders modulo $m$ is untidy in general. When $n>2$, every odd element in $\Bbb Z_{2^n}$ can be written uniquely as (congruent to) $\pm 5^k$ for some $0\le k<2^{n-2}$, a representation which makes it easy to compute its order (it's $2^{n-2}/\gcd(2^{n-2},k)$ when $k>0$). But figuring out the value of $k$ for the residue class is the discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: On the contrary:  although calculating orders modulo $m$ is indeed untidy in general, KCd's answer shows that it's very tidy in the case where $m$ is a power of $2$ (or some other sufficiently small prime).

Comment: You don't have to aim to write the odd number $a$ in the form $\pm 5^k \bmod 2^n$ to compute the order of $a \bmod 2^n$, but can just directly deal with computing how much $a-1$ is divisible by $2$ and get the order from that (if $a \equiv 1 \bmod 4$). So one doesn't need anything resembling the discrete log problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the case $n=8$ you can just brute force it (there are only 128 odd numbers $\mod 2^8$).

You can easily compute the multiplicative order of an element in $\mathbb{Z}/2^n$, but there is no known closed form.

To compute it, a simple method is the following - you know that $a^{2^{n-2}}=1 \mod 2^n$. Therefore $o(a) \mid 2^{n-2}$. Therefore $o(a)=2^k$ for some $0 \leq k <n-2$, so it is enough to try the $n-2$ different powers of $a$.
So compute $a, a^2, a^{2^2}, a^{2^3}, \ldots$ until $a^{2^k}=1 \mod 2^n$, and $2^k$ will be the order of $a$.
Note that $a \to a^2 \to a^{2^2} \to a^{2^3} \to \cdots$ is simply a sequence of squarings. So you need to compute at most $n-2$ squarings modulo $2^n$.